# Type A is assignable to the constraint of type T, but T could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint A | B

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I get this error from TS and it doesn't make any sense,
because my T generic is fully compatible with types A | B, because it extends from it! It's is not true what the error says that you can instantiate it with a incompatible type.

```
type MyProps<T extends A | B> = {
   initial: T;
   onChange: (value: T) => void;
}

function MyComponent<T extends A | B>(props: MyProps<T>){

    const changeHandler = (value: T) => {
       ...
       props.onChange(value);
    };

    return <SomeOtherComponent onChange={changeHandler} ... />
}
```

The error is thrown forthe `onChange` property of SomeOtherComponent, but the type of onChange in that component is `(value: A | B) => void`, so it's fully compatible with T.

What am I missing here?

---

a link to example in ts playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCDeAoRBfZpIwEJNcgLgJ4AOAptALKEAKATgPbEQA8AKtKQB76kB2AJjFjQAPtCwA+aAF5oSaAoCWvRfkVgQALmisA3IgXR6vAMIALMLwDmpbQAoAbhoCutnQEoZUh-UX99aIgAZs68wGrGlIQm9AC2xMZ8+Gwc3HyCcKLiEnbEDEzaVHSMLKwS7riG0MDGEPjVFtakABKW-CCktDLQji5urJ7SUvIGVQp5JQB0xuaWNr0gru76VSj6owq0pPjOtLzQzADKcaQA8vhmnTHxibz1M4020vDAjy1tHbQo0AD0EnjBULhRSRY6xM4XK5xBK8JK5fIQbTwIymN72JyLNywMRYQbeXz8aAoCrIFBAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers have pointed out it's wise to ensure you're not narrowing the type, by keeping the `T extends A | B` all the way down.

In instances like this (where I am deliberately creating a function to be used for the value of a *known* prop); I find that typing `changeHandler` upfront can be useful as you can expect that `changeHandler` will be of the correct type.

If the prop is just being passed through and called, maybe I wouldn't bother with redefining it, but I assume this has just been done for the purpose of the question.

```js
class A {

}

class B {

}

type MyOtherProps<T extends A | B> = {
   onChange: (value: T) => void;
}

function SomeOtherComponent<T extends A |B> (props: MyOtherProps<T> ) {

}


type MyProps<T extends A | B> = {
   initial: T;
   onChange: (value: T) => void;
}

function MyComponent<T extends A | B>(props: MyProps<T>){

    const changeHandler: MyOtherProps<T>["onChange"] = (value) => {
       props.onChange(value);
    };

    return <SomeOtherComponent onChange={changeHandler} />
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`SomeOtherComponent` expects an `onChange` property of type `(value: A | B) => void`; that is, it expects an `onChange` property that will accept *any* value of either type `A` or type `B`.

You're trying to give it an `onChange` property of type `(value: T) => void`, where `T` could be (for example) just `A` or just `B`; that is, you're trying to give it an `onChange` property that may not accept certain values that it needs `onChange` to accept.

The technical term that you can search for is *contravariance*; you can use a function with more-*permissive* parameter-types than is expected, but not one with more-*restrictive* parameter-types, because then you're imposing requirements on the caller that it may not satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `T extends A | B`, your change handler is accepting the value of type `T`, while in `SomeOtherComponent`'s `onChange` method you have a function that accepts the value of type `A | B`

Here we are narrowing down the scope `T extends A | B` but `T` can not be assigned to the `A | B` type. If you change your `SomeOtherComponent` like below it will work

```js
function SomeOtherComponent<T extends A | B>(props: { onChange: (value: T) => void }){

}
```

when your function definition is like this

```
const changeHandler = (value: T) => {
   props.onChange(value);
};
```

what you are doing is passing this function definition to your `SomeOtherComponent`'s `A | B` type which is like passing `T` -> `A | B` but there could be reverse way around `A | B` -> `T`.